# What is "kickseed sudo: authentication failure"

Tags: boot, login, authentication

I used a PXE server to install a custom Ubuntu iso.

After login with `ssh`, I found an error log in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Aug  3 02:06:14 kickseed sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=wind uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/ttyS0 ruser=wind rhost=  user=wind
```

What does it mean? How could I solve this error?

BTW, `wind` is the username.

Comment: Is your user in the group that owns "tty=/dev/ttyS0"?

Comment: @Rinzwind What do you mean by "owns tty=/dev/ttyS0"? Do you mean if my user has the permission to login from `/dev/ttyS0`?